# EditText не удаляет строку, если при повторном вводе вводится меньше символов

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-edittext

При вводе в поле EditText меньше символов, чем было до этого он их просто складывает, т.е. если при первом вводе ввести ttt, а при втором s, то вывод будет stt. Помогите сделать так, чтобы как-то чистилось поле, либо может как-то чистить буфер. Ещё приложил пару скриншотов работы.

Файл MainActivity.java:

```
package ru.atbattle.chasie.socetclient;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telecom.DisconnectCause;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
//import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Appindex;
//import com.google.android.gms.common.spi.GoogleApiClient;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.io. *;
import java.net. *;
import java.lang. *;
import java.util. *;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editText, editText3, editText2;
Button button, button2, button3, button4;
Spinner spinner;
Socket s;
String IPn, str, str1;
InputStream is;
OutputStream os;
byte buf1[] = new byte[512];
byte buf2[] = new byte[512];
int len1;
Thread th;
AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> readMsg;
AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> writeMsg;
AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> connect;
AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> disconnect;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
//    private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    spinner = (Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
}



public void getConnection(View view) {

    connect = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                s = new Socket(params[0], 9999);
                is = s.getInputStream();
                os = s.getOutputStream();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean param) {
            editText3.setText(((param)?"Connected!":"Error!"));
        }
    };

    connect.execute(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
}

public void getDisconnection(View view) {

    disconnect = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                s.close();
                is.close();
                os.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean param) {
            editText3.setText(((param)?"Disconnected!":"Error!"));
        }

    };

    disconnect.execute();
}

public void SendReceive(View view) {

    writeMsg = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                os.write(params[0].getBytes(), 0, params[0].length());
                os.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    writeMsg.execute(new String[] { editText.getText().toString() });

}

public void Accept(View view) {

    readMsg = new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            editText2.setText(null);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                int bytes = is.read(buf1, 0, 512);
                os.flush();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.getMessage();
            }

            return new String(buf1, 0);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            editText2.setText(message);
        }
    };


    readMsg.execute();
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

[image: Проблема, которую нужно исправить(1 скриншот)]
[image: Проблема, которую нужно исправить(2 скриншот)]

Comment: После надписи "Файл MainActivity.java: "

Answer (score 1):

В `AsyncTask readMsg`, в методе `onPostExecute`, сначала editText2 присвоить пустую строку, а затем уже сообщение:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    editText2.setText("");
    editText2.setText(message);
}
```

Comment: Это не решило проблему, вот скрин вывода
[скриншот](http://i.imgur.com/v9q6Dg2.png)